# Practice program not making deadlock as intended

Tags: c, pthreads, deadlock

I'm trying to learn about deadlocks in my operating systems class, and, no matter how many times I run it, the program I made isn't deadlocking. The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int resource1;
int resource2;
void *causeDeadlock1();
void *causeDeadlock2();
void wait(int r);
void signal(int r);
pthread_t tid[2];

int main()
{
    resource1 = 1;
    resource2 = 1;
    pthread_create((&tid[0]), NULL, &causeDeadlock1, NULL);
    pthread_create((&tid[1]), NULL, &causeDeadlock2, NULL);
    return(0);
}

void wait(int r)
{
    while(r<1);
    printf("Done waiting\n");
    r--;
}

void signal(int r)
{
    r++;
}

void* causeDeadlock1()
{
    wait(resource1);
    wait(resource2);

    printf("Thread 1 is running with both resources.\n");

    signal(resource1);
    signal(resource2);

    printf("Thread 1 is done.\n");
}

void *causeDeadlock2()
{
    wait(resource2);
    wait(resource1);

    printf("Thread 2 is running with both resources.\n");

    signal(resource2);
    signal(resource1);

    printf("Thread 2 is done.\n");
}
```

When I run it, I commonly see no output, but I'm also returned to console normally. I would think the reason that is is that the threads never get to print that they have the resources or that they're done because they get stuck forever in the wait function's while loop. However, if that's the case, shouldn't the program hang instead of returning me to console like nothing happened?

Comment: the function: `wait()` is a well known system function, usually used to delay until some child process exits.  It is a very poor programming practice to call your functions by the system function names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues with your program.  **EDIT:** Four, if you also count B. Wolf's answer.

First of all, your `wait` and `signal` functions don't cause any data races.  They both affect not the real resource (`int r`), but the copy passed as a parameter.  Remember that C uses call-by-value.  You should fix that, e.g.

```
void wait(int *r) {
  while (*r<1);       // still wrong, see below!
  (*r)--;
}

void signal(int *r) {
  (*r)++;
}

... wait(&resource1);
... signal(&resource1);
```

Second, even if `wait` is changed as above, the test `*r >= 1` that exits the `while` loop and the decrement operation should be performed **atomically**.  Otherwise, there is a chance that two or more threads acquire the resource at the same time and the semantics of your `wait` action is flawed.

Third, even if you fix the second issue too, your program **may** deadlock, it is not **guaranteed** to deadlock.  Deadlock will happen only if the threads' actions are interleaved in the following way:

1. `causeDeadlock1` acquires `resource1`
2. `causeDeadlock2` acquires `resource2`
3. `causeDeadlock1` waits for `resource2`
4. `causeDeadlock2` waits for `resource1`

where it is important that 1 and 2 (in any relative order) happen before 3 and 4 (again in any relative order).

Most often, I would expect that a thread acquiring its first resource would manage to acquire the second resource too, before the other thread even has a chance to start executing.  Therefore, I would not bet on a deadlock, if you just run this once.  Put the bodies of functions `causeDeadlock1` and `causeDeadlock2` in loops and you'll definitely see a deadlock (after you fix the other two issues).

Comment: How can I make the decrement operations atomic? I have next to no experience with either C or multithreading.

Comment: You could use a mutex (i.e., a binary semaphore), or a condition variable.  Pthreads implement both.  This is a long story, however, and I suggest that you spend some time studying concurrency and synchronization at this point.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're not getting any printout is that the main thread is exiting. You should add this before returning from main()

```
void *aa;
...
pthread_join(tid[0],&aa);
pthread_join(tid[1],&aa);

return(0);
```